# GMM clusters - labelling

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, gaussian

I am trying to find the labels corresponding to the points of a GMM cluster, after the clusters have been assigned. This is akin to the estimator.labels_ capability in KMeans. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Try reformulating your question, show what you've tried and what result you want. The question sounds trivial but it's hard to guess https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use `predict`.

As seen in the example here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-cluster-comparison-py